# Python xpath, class second element

Tags: python, class, xpath, scrapy, element

how I get only **bold** element out of that script ?

```
<a class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-border show-one" data-one="bold" data-listing="12345">
                                        <i class="icon-one-1"></i>&nbsp;<span>Show one</span>
                                    </a>
```

Tanx for help :)

my current xpath is : response.xpath('//a[@class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-border show-one"]').extract()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
response.xpath('//a[@data-one="bold"]/span/text()')
```

You will get *Show one* as the result - it is your bold element

If you need your data-one element, you can extract it this way on each page:

```
xpath('//*[@class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-border show-one"]/@data-one').extract()
```

Comment: Tanx for reply :) But if the value of "data-one" is different in every page, but structure stays same ? basically I need this bold to text :)

Comment: @ThéGenerous, I can not get what you actually need. You need to get span element (Show one in this case) in every page where data-one="bold"?

Comment: there's a 30000 pages and "data-one" equals like bold421, bold1124, bold41255......and so on. I need those "bold...." In span tag the "bold..." is blocked by javascript . I need to get this from class. :) I hope you understand, and thank you for your patience. :)

Comment: You are very welcome :) But in the future try to explain your question as clear as possible, since I understood it correct after your comment only)